# R function won't use my arguments. Cannot rename column of dataframe from within the function

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I wrote a function:

```r
ltd_EGST <- function (var, x, newvana="name1", string1="con", string2="pro") {
    print (table (var))
    x$w12d_gr <- ifelse(as.numeric(var)>2,1,0)
    x$w12d_gr <- factor(x$w12d_gr, levels = c(0,1), labels = c(string1,string2))
    print (table (x$w12d_gr))
    x_w <- svydesign(ids=~0, weights = ~persgew, data = x)
    t <- svytable(~w12d_gr+welle, x_w)
    tt <- round(prop.table(t,2)*100, digits=0)
    w12d <- tt[2,] # Zustimmungswerte only
    print(str(w12d))
    w12d <- as.data.frame(w12d)
    rename(w12d, newvana = w12d)
    }
```

Producing the following dataframe:

```r
    newvana
2001      17
2002      17
2003      20
2004      18
2005      19
2006      19
2007      14
2008      17
2010      15
2011      14
2012      16
2013      12
2014      13
2015      20
2016      16
2017      14
2018      18
2019      21
2020      15
2021      13
```

My question:
Why won't the function use the newvana argument from the interface inside the function?
As you can see, it will name the column newvana, but not "name1".

Why is that?

Comment: My guess is tidyverse non-standard evaluation. You could try the base R setNames function instead

Comment: hi! thanks mate! that worked perfectly. I have been sitting for hours now in front of this. i replaced the rename-fun  with w12d <- setnames(w12d, newvana).